# Two Active Storage attachments on one model - one works, the other doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a Ruby on Rails 7 project with a model named chapters.rb and it has two active storage attachments: video and cover_image. In my form I have a file field for each and I have double checked that everything is named correctly. The problem is that I can only upload a video (Quicktime) but not a cover_image (jpg). When I upload a video the form submits and very quickly redirects to the show page and shows the uploaded video as expected.

However, when I try to upload the cover_image I get a dialog box with the error "Error reading [whatever the filename is]". In the javascript console I get this error: Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. (WebKitBlobResource error 4.). There is nothing showing on my Rails console. Both the video and the cover_image appear to be configured correctly and similarly. It's absolutely baffling. Any ideas?

Here is the relevant code:

```
  belongs_to :curriculum
  # has_one :curriculum_video, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sections, dependent: :destroy
  has_one_attached :cover_image
  has_one_attached :video

end
```

```
<%= form_with(model: [@curriculum, @chapter], class: "contents") do |form| %>
  <% if @chapter.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation" class="bg-red-50 text-red-500 px-3 py-2 font-medium rounded-lg mt-3">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@chapter.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this chapter from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% chapter.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <%= form.hidden_field :curriculum_id %>

  <div class="my-5">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title, class: "block shadow rounded-md border border-gray-200 outline-none px-3 py-2 mt-2 w-full" %>
  </div>

  <div class="my-5">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_field :description, class: "block shadow rounded-md border border-gray-200 outline-none px-3 py-2 mt-2 w-full" %>
  </div>

  <div class="my-5">
    <%= form.label :chapter_video %>
    <%= form.file_field :video, direct_upload: true, class: "block shadow rounded-md border border-gray-200 outline-none px-3 py-2 mt-2 w-full"%>
  </div> 

  <div class="my-5">
    <%= form.label "Cover Image" %>
    <%= form.file_field :cover_image, direct_upload: true, class: "block shadow rounded-md border border-gray-200 outline-none px-3 py-2 mt-2 w-full"%>
  </div>
  


  <div class="inline">
    <%= form.submit class: "rounded-lg py-3 px-5 bg-blue-600 text-white inline-block font-medium cursor-pointer" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script>
document.querySelector('.contents').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  console.log('Form submitted!');
});

</script>
```

```
# Relevant chapters_controller.rb
# GET /chapters/1/edit
  def edit
    authorize @chapter
  end

  # POST /chapters or /chapters.json
  def create
    # @chapter = Chapter.new(chapter_params)
    @chapter = @curriculum.chapters.build(chapter_params)
    authorize @chapter

    respond_to do |format|
      if @chapter.save
        format.html { redirect_to curriculum_path(@curriculum), notice: "Chapter was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @chapter }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @chapter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /chapters/1 or /chapters/1.json
  def update
    authorize @chapter

    respond_to do |format|
      if @chapter.update(chapter_params)
        format.html { redirect_to curriculum_chapter_path(@curriculum, @chapter), notice: "Chapter was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @chapter }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @chapter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Have you tried to attach only the picture (i.e. no video)? Also, what happens if you don't use direct_upload?

Comment: UPDATE! Well this is embarrassing. It turns out that the images I was trying to upload were located in a OneDrive folder and they were referenced in my Finder but not actually downloaded on my disk. Apparently my OneDrive syncing is failing so the file was not being retrieved from the cloud when selected. When I tried an image that was confirmed to be on my local drive I was able to upload without any problems. Thanks all for attempting to solve this problem.

Comment: PS. You can remove `<%= form.hidden_field :curriculum_id %>` as you're passing the curriculum_id though the segment in the URI.

Answer (score 0):

For attaching multiple files to a a single model in ActiveStorage, we can make use of has_many_attached.

For example:
`has_many_attached :files`
use the above one insted of has_one_attached

Comment: I think that is for attaching multiple attachments of the same type (eg multiple pictures etc). Not sure this works in this instance.

Comment: Hmm, looks like bad idea. How to determine which is the cover image and which is the video? In general it is always more convenient to use `has_one_attached`. Even for multiple attachments (just use `has_many` with another model)

Comment: Yeah, I definitely must use has_one_attached here. And from what I understand it is OK to use multiple has_one_attached or multiple has_many_attached statements per model. I have even disabled the has_one_attached :video statement to confirm whether it's a matter of having more than one statement. But it did not fix the issue.